# Errors when trying to update a fresh debian 10.5 KDE installation

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

After typing `sudo apt update` into the terminal, I get this output:

```
Hit:1 http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Ign:2 http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian buster/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian buster/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.228.252.133 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian buster/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Because of this, I can't update my system at all.
I'm using Debian 10.5 KDE. I installed the **debian-live-10.5.0-amd64-kde+nonfree.iso**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error shouldn’t *prevent* you from upgrading; the other repositories are still updated. `apt upgrade` should allow you to upgrade.

However “buster/updates” doesn’t exist on the main repositories, so you might as well remove it; edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the `ftp.hu.debian.org/debian buster/updates` line. While you’re at it, check that you have a `security.debian.org` line — I suspect that the `buster/updates` error comes from a change made to that:

```
deb http://security.debian.org buster/updates main
```

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file should end up as follows:

```
deb http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free contrib 
deb-src http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free contrib 

deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free 

deb http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie so I don't know what I should delete here. Don't want to delete anything important. I edited my question with the contents of my sources.list file.